# Humans, unwittingly living within a bell jar, are tasked with meaningless research to keep them busy, while aliens observe them from the outside

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I'm trying to identify a short story I read years ago - around the 1960s, I think, though I don't remember where I read it. Here's what I remember about the plot:

A scholarly researcher uses a time viewer to track everything that happened on a square meter or so of a lawn over time. He dutifully enters these details into a log, but gradually realizes how meaningless the task is.

Eventually, he realizes that he and the other researchers are living in a glass cage, and he can sense the aliens (of enormously superior intelligence) watching from the outside. They have created this task to keep the poor humans busy and entertained.

Anyone know the story? The imagery has stuck in my head and I'd like to refer to it in my teaching about history.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Could you clarify whether this is a short story or a novel? And if it is a short story, did you read it in an anthology or a magazine?

Comment: @LogicDictates I'm confused, what critical issue didn't my suggested edit fix?

Comment: @Waited 6 months after MSE qban - My preference is to keep the number of revisions in a post's edit history down to a minimum. After all the changes I made to the question, I don't think there were any critical issues outstanding that justified another entry in this post's revision history. Also, I don't think the history tag was really appropriate for this question, nor do I think it was necessary to hide the last part of the description with a spoiler box. People reading a story ID question should expect spoilers; it comes with the territory.

Comment: It was a short story, but I'm honestly not sure where I read it. The imagery has stuck in my head and I'd like to refer to it in my teaching about history.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

["The Fence"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57013), a short story by [Clifford D. Simak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_D._Simak), first published in [*Space Science Fiction*, September 1952](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?181605+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Space_Science_Fiction_v01n02_1952-09/page/n36/mode/2up). You may have read it in one of [these compilations](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?57013). (I have it in a paperback edition of Simak's collection [*Strangers in the Universe*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?33622).)

**A scholarly researcher uses a time viewer to track everything that happened on a square meter or so of a lawn over time. He dutifully enters these details into a log,**

An acre, not a square meter:

> "History," said Craig.
>
> "Oh," said the counselor. "A most engaging subject. I have known a number of gentlemen who were quite wrapped up in history."
>
> "I specialize," said Craig. "One acre."
>
> "Acre?" asked the counselor, not a little puzzled. "I'm not quite sure . . ."
>
> "The history of one acre," Craig told him. "Trace it back, you know, with a temporal viewer. Hour to hour, day to day. Record, in detail, and with appropriate comment and deduction, everything that transpired upon the acre."

**but gradually realizes how meaningless the task is.**

> "I realized, said Craig, that no one would care. I would spend years at the study and I would publish my findings and I would give copies to my friends and acquaintances and they would thank me and put the book up on the shelf and never take it down again. I would deposit copies in libraries and you know yourself that no one ever goes to libraries. The only one who would ever read the thing would be myself."

**Eventually, he realizes that he and the other researchers are living in a glass cage,**

Not glass but some kind of weird barrier which Craig discovers when he goes for a walk:

> It was then he discovered he was slipping. It appeared that he was going straight ahead but, as a matter of fact, he was slipping sidewise as he walked. It was just as if there were something smooth and slippery in front of him that translated his forward movement without his knowing it. Like a fence that he couldn't see or sense.

**and he can sense the aliens (of enormously superior intelligence) watching from the outside.**

> Something flickered in front of him. For a moment it seemed that he saw an eye, one single staring eye, looking straight at him. He stood rigid and the sense of being looked at grew and now it seemed that there were strange shadows on the grass beyond the fence that was invisible. As if someone, or something, that he couldn't see was standing there and looking at him, watching with amusement his efforts to walk through the fence.
>
> Hew lifted a hand and thrust it out in front of him and there was no fence, but his hand and arm slipped sidewise and did not go forward more than a foot or so.
>
> He felt the kindness, then, the kindness and the pity and the vast superiority.
>
> And he turned and fled.

**They have created this task to keep the poor humans busy and entertained.**

> "You said this afternoon," said Craig, "that we were kept. You mean they're keeping us?"
>
> Sherman nodded. "That's the way I have it figured. They're keeping us, watching over us, taking care of us. There's nothing tht we can't have for the simple asking. They're taking real good care of us."
>
> "But why?"
>
> "I don't know," said Sherman. "A zoo, maybe. A reservation, maybe. A place to preserve the last of a species. They don't mean us any harm."
>
> "I know they don't," said Craig. "I felt them. That's what frightened me."

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much!